# Run LLVM test-suite on HPI shows script not found error, how to fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, gem5

I have se-benchmarks I tried to run it using gem5, following this tutorial https://github.com/arm-university/arm-gem5-rsk/wiki but it shows me this error (Script intMM not found). intMM is an application inside the se-benchmarks.

I use the fowwoing command to run it

```
 ./build/ARM/gem5.opt -d se_results/intMM configs/example/arm/starter_se.py --cpu="hpi" /home/Ali/se-benchmarks
```

every time this error happened to me.

```
warn: CheckedInt already exists in allParams. This may be caused by the Python 2.7 compatibility layer.
warn: Enum already exists in allParams. This may be caused by the Python 2.7 compatibility layer.
warn: ScopedEnum already exists in allParams. This may be caused by the Python 2.7 compatibility layer.
gem5 Simulator System.  http://gem5.org
gem5 is copyrighted software; use the --copyright option for details.

gem5 version 20.0.0.2
gem5 compiled Jun 28 2020 08:20:55
gem5 started Jun 29 2020 00:59:57
gem5 executing on Ali-VirtualBox, pid 6640
command line: ./build/ARM/gem5.opt -d se_results/intMM configs/example/arm/starter_se.py --cpu=hpi /home/Ali/se-benchmarks

info: 1. command and arguments: ['/home/Ali/se-benchmarks']
Global frequency set at 1000000000000 ticks per second
warn: No dot file generated. Please install pydot to generate the dot file and pdf.
warn: DRAM device capacity (8192 Mbytes) does not match the address range assigned (1024 Mbytes)
warn: DRAM device capacity (8192 Mbytes) does not match the address range assigned (1024 Mbytes)
panic: panic condition sz != 2 occurred: Couldn't read magic bytes from object file
Memory Usage: 2245340 KBytes
Program aborted at tick 0
--- BEGIN LIBC BACKTRACE ---
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_Z15print_backtracev+0x30)[0x5610ee5504a0]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_Z12abortHandleri+0x4e)[0x5610ee563fee]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x153c0)[0x7f559b8283c0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcb)[0x7f559ae0f18b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x12b)[0x7f559adee859]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(+0xc212b5)[0x5610eccf82b5]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN6Loader13ImageFileDataC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x7f5)[0x5610edd321c5]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN6Loader16createObjectFileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEb+0x46)[0x5610edd32876]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN13ProcessParams6createEv+0x4c)[0x5610ee5a3b7c]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(+0x2000843)[0x5610ee0d7843]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(+0xd03e57)[0x5610ecddae57]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x9701)[0x7f559b94e381]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7f8)[0x7f559b944628]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6f81)[0x7f559b94bc01]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7f8)[0x7f559b944628]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6f81)[0x7f559b94bc01]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7f8)[0x7f559b944628]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6f81)[0x7f559b94bc01]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7f8)[0x7f559b944628]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6f81)[0x7f559b94bc01]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7f8)[0x7f559b944628]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6f81)[0x7f559b94bc01]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7f8)[0x7f559b944628]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6f81)[0x7f559b94bc01]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7f8)[0x7f559b944628]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6f81)[0x7f559b94bc01]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7f8)[0x7f559b944628]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x19)[0x7f559b944b39]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6e76)[0x7f559b94baf6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7f8)[0x7f559b944628]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6f81)[0x7f559b94bc01]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7f8)[0x7f559b944628]
--- END LIBC BACKTRACE ---
Aborted (core dumped)
Ali@Ali-VirtualBox:~/gem5$ ./build/ARM/gem5.opt -d se_results/ intMM configs/example/arm/starter_se.py --cpu="hpi" /home/Ali/se-benchmarks
warn: CheckedInt already exists in allParams. This may be caused by the Python 2.7 compatibility layer.
warn: Enum already exists in allParams. This may be caused by the Python 2.7 compatibility layer.
warn: ScopedEnum already exists in allParams. This may be caused by the Python 2.7 compatibility layer.
gem5 Simulator System.  http://gem5.org
gem5 is copyrighted software; use the --copyright option for details.

gem5 version 20.0.0.2
gem5 compiled Jun 28 2020 08:20:55
gem5 started Jun 29 2020 01:00:16
gem5 executing on Ali-VirtualBox, pid 6645
command line: ./build/ARM/gem5.opt -d se_results/ intMM configs/example/arm/starter_se.py --cpu=hpi /home/Ali/se-benchmarks

Script intMM not found
Usage
=====
  gem5.opt [gem5 options] script.py [script options]

gem5 is copyrighted software; use the --copyright option for details.

Options
=======
--version               show program's version number and exit
--help, -h              show this help message and exit
--build-info, -B        Show build information
--copyright, -C         Show full copyright information
--readme, -R            Show the readme
--outdir=DIR, -d DIR    Set the output directory to DIR [Default: m5out]
--redirect-stdout, -r   Redirect stdout (& stderr, without -e) to file
--redirect-stderr, -e   Redirect stderr to file
--stdout-file=FILE      Filename for -r redirection [Default: simout]
--stderr-file=FILE      Filename for -e redirection [Default: simerr]
--listener-mode={on,off,auto}
                        Port (e.g., gdb) listener mode (auto: Enable if
                        running interactively) [Default: auto]
--listener-loopback-only
                        Port listeners will only accept connections over the
                        loopback device
--interactive, -i       Invoke the interactive interpreter after running the
                        script
--pdb                   Invoke the python debugger before running the script
--path=PATH[:PATH], -p PATH[:PATH]
                        Prepend PATH to the system path when invoking the
                        script
--quiet, -q             Reduce verbosity
--verbose, -v           Increase verbosity

Statistics Options
------------------
--stats-file=FILE       Sets the output file for statistics [Default:
                        stats.txt]
--stats-help            Display documentation for available stat visitors

Configuration Options
---------------------
--dump-config=FILE      Dump configuration output file [Default: config.ini]
--json-config=FILE      Create JSON output of the configuration [Default:
                        config.json]
--dot-config=FILE       Create DOT & pdf outputs of the configuration
                        [Default: config.dot]
--dot-dvfs-config=FILE  Create DOT & pdf outputs of the DVFS configuration
                        [Default: none]

Debugging Options
-----------------
--debug-break=TICK[,TICK]
                        Create breakpoint(s) at TICK(s) (kills process if no
                        debugger attached)
--debug-help            Print help on debug flags
--debug-flags=FLAG[,FLAG]
                        Sets the flags for debug output (-FLAG disables a
                        flag)
--debug-start=TICK      Start debug output at TICK
--debug-end=TICK        End debug output at TICK
--debug-file=FILE       Sets the output file for debug [Default: cout]
--debug-ignore=EXPR     Ignore EXPR sim objects
--remote-gdb-port=REMOTE_GDB_PORT
                        Remote gdb base port (set to 0 to disable listening)

Help Options
------------
--list-sim-objects      List all built-in SimObjects, their params and default
                        values
```

I use ubuntu 20 on VirtualBox.

Comment: The actual error message is "panic: panic condition sz != 2 occurred: Couldn't read magic bytes from object file" It suggests that the ELF file used is not in a proper format. Can you run a C hello world? Also try `file <efl-file>` to ensure that it is an arm executable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the instructions there were simply not super precise, you are pointing to a directory but it should be the executable instead:

```
./build/ARM/gem5.opt -d se_results/intMM configs/example/arm/starter_se.py --cpu="hpi" \
  /home/Ali/se-benchmarks/IntMM
```

Also note however that some of the benchmarks, including `IntMM` might take a very long time to complete, so maybe you want to test that everything is working with one of the faster ones such as `Bubblesort`, `Quicksort` or `Towers`.